# Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory gives internal storage

Tags: android

I'm saving a picture like so:

```
File dcimDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM);
File picsDir = new File(dcimDir, "MyPics");
picsDir.mkdirs(); //make if not exist
File newFile = new File(picsDir, "image.png"));
OutputStream os;
try {
    os = new FileOutputStream(newFile);

    target.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 100, os);

    os.flush();
    os.close();
    b.recycle();
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

However, when I look for the image through windows it is in the internal memory, the gallery confirms this:

[image: On PC]

[image: Gallery details]

This last one is confusing, it says internal memory, but then also has `sdcard0` in file path.

So when does external not mean external? Is it a device set up thing, or an I miss-using/miss-understanding `getExternalStoragePublicDirectory`?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The MTP engine sometimes reports `getExternalStorageDirectory()` as "Internal Storage", which is why it shows up under that name when you mount the device as a volume on Windows, Linux, etc.

External storage has always meant the storage that the user can access by means of a USB cable. The "Internal Storage" label is probably used on devices where external storage is part of the on-board ("internal") flash.

Comment: Excuse ignorance, what's MTP? A google of "MTP engine" turns up agricultural engines! "Android MTP engine", not much better.

Comment: And how should I be getting a path to the SD card if `getExternalStorageDirectory` is behaving this way?

Comment: @weston: "Excuse ignorance, what's MTP?" -- Media Transfer Protocol, the USB protocol spoken by Android 3.0+ for outside access to external storage. "And how should I be getting a path to the SD card if getExternalStorageDirectory is behaving this way?" -- you should be using `getExternalStorageDirectory()` (or, better yet, `getExternalStoragePublicDirectory()` or `getExternalFilesDir()`, rather than cluttering up the root of external storage). http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal

Comment: Thanks, but I am using `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM)` and it isn't placing on the physical SD card.

Comment: @weston: It is not supposed to place it on the physical SD card, according to the manufacturer of your device. Quoting the documentation that I linked to in my previous comment: "It's possible that a device using a partition of the internal storage for the external storage may also offer an SD card slot. In this case, the SD card is not part of the external storage and your app cannot access it (the extra storage is intended only for user-provided media that the system scans)".

Comment: Ok, I do now understand why it works this way. Doesn't help me place files on the sd card. My users do not understand how their built in camera apps can use the sd card and my app can't. So, you are saying that writing to sd card is impossible if the device has internal storage?

Comment: @weston: There is no documented and supported means of working with non-standard storage locations. If you hunt around, you will find unreliable recipes that you can attempt to use, mostly relying upon some assumptions regarding the underlying Linux filesystem structure. I do not recommend this.

Comment: @CommonsWare: i'm facing the same issue as weston. After all I'm confused very much. I mean how to ensure that you really save files to the physical SD Card? I want to export file to a specific folder, which the user knows, can get it from SD Card, and process further in desktop machine. My file is XML file, I want to use the Documents folder, or the root of SD Card could be OK as well. Do you have any android provided solution for this?

Comment: @pillesoft: "I mean how to ensure that you really save files to the physical SD Card?" -- you do not have filesystem access to removable storage on Android 4.4+, outside of a couple of app-specific locations. "Do you have any android provided solution for this?" -- what you want is not strictly possible prior to perhaps Android 7.0, where you can get access to a `StorageVolume` (with user approval). For Android 5.0-6.0, you can use `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE` to have the user give you access to a document tree, but it might not be the magic one you are seeking.